# `import sass from 'sass'` is deprecated

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, gulp

UPD: Thanks a lot for @Moshe Katz and @Zac Anger the problem was in the path to  scss!!!

How can i fix this problems?

my code in scss.js:

[image: scss]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV9oq.png]

```
import dartSass from 'sass';`
import gulpSass from 'gulp-sass';
import rename from 'gulp-rename';`

const sass = gulpSass(dartSass);`
```

i take this problems

```
`$ gulp
`import sass from 'sass'` is deprecated.
Please use `import * as sass from 'sass'` instead.`
```

when i change code for

```
import *as dartSass from 'sass';
import gulpSass from 'gulp-sass';
import rename from 'gulp-rename';

const sass = gulpSass(dartSass);
```

i'll take another one

`$ gulp [20:41:22] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\Filancer_gulp\gulpfile.js [20:41:22] Starting 'default'... [20:41:22] Starting 'reset'... [20:41:22] Finished 'reset' after 8.86 ms [20:41:22] Starting 'copy'... [20:41:22] Starting 'html'... [20:41:22] Starting 'scss'... [20:41:22] 'scss' errored after 17 ms [20:41:22] Error: Invalid glob argument: undefined`

Comment: You are getting the same error using both the old import and the new import, so the import is not your issue. The import issue is only a warning, not an error.

Comment: Please show all of your gulp code, not just those four lines.

Comment: Changing your import is correct, [the default export is deprecated](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/blob/3367abe1612c450d3bdceb6be55cf3bf22bae35c/tool/grind.dart#L266). Your gulpfile is where your real problem is, you've got an invalid pattern somewhere most likely.

Comment: i've added gulp picture

Comment: why are you putting source map in .src, you should use gulp-sourcemap

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:
Change the line `import *as dartSass from 'sass';`
to `import * as dartSass from 'sass';`.